# printing result array with toString

Tags: java

i tried to add `toString` to print result array... but i got exceptions other users hints not working for me... where is the problem .... please send me write code in write place
project Name : Skyline
code on gitHub : https://github.com/mouhyi/Algorithms/blob/master/SkyLine.java

i tried this and i got these exceptions: 
images : 
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLdBm.png
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/r311t.png

but can't work

My code :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class sakhteman

{

public static ArrayList<Point> findsakhteman(Building[] sakhtemanha){
    int n = sakhtemanha.length;
    if(n == 1){
        ArrayList<Point> sl = new ArrayList<Point>();
        sl.add(new Point(sakhtemanha[0].left, sakhtemanha[0].height));
        sl.add(new Point(sakhtemanha[0].right, 0));
        return sl;
    }
    ArrayList<Point> sl1 = findsakhteman(Arrays.copyOfRange(sakhtemanha, 0,n/2 ));
    ArrayList<Point> sl2 = findsakhteman(Arrays.copyOfRange(sakhtemanha, n/2+1, n ));
    return merge(sl1, sl2);
}
public static ArrayList<Point> merge(ArrayList<Point> sl1, ArrayList<Point> sl2){
    ArrayList<Point> sakhteman = new ArrayList<Point>();
    int curH1=0, curH2=0, curX=0;
    while(!sl1.isEmpty() && !sl2.isEmpty()){
        if( sl1.get(sl1.size()-1).x < sl2.get(sl1.size()-1).x ){
            curX = sl1.get(sl1.size()-1).x;
            curH1 = sl1.get(sl1.size()-1).y;
            sl1.remove(sl1.size()-1);
            sakhteman.add(new Point(curX, Math.max(curH1, curH2)));
        }else{
            curX = sl2.get(sl2.size()-1).x;
            curH1 = sl2.get(sl2.size()-1).y;
            sl2.remove(sl1.size()-1);
            sakhteman.add(new Point(curX, Math.max(curH1, curH2)));
        }
    }
    if(sl1.isEmpty()){
        sakhteman.addAll(sl2);
    }else if(sl2.isEmpty()){
        sakhteman.addAll(sl1);
    }
    return sakhteman;
}
public static class Building{
    int left, right, height;
    public Building(int left, int right, int height) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.height = height;

    }
    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
    }
}
public static class Point{
    public int x, y;
    public Point(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
public static class runClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sakhteman.Building[] arr = new Building[] {
            new sakhteman.Building(1, 11, 5),
            new sakhteman.Building(2, 6, 7),
            new sakhteman.Building(3, 13, 9),
            new sakhteman.Building(12, 7, 16),
            new sakhteman.Building(14, 3, 25),
            new sakhteman.Building(19, 18, 22),
            new sakhteman.Building(23, 13, 29),
            new sakhteman.Building(24, 4, 28)
        };
        ArrayList<Point> res=findsakhteman(arr);

        System.out.println(res.toString()); 
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing a recursive loop that is never ending in the function findsakhteman (line 12), check your stopping condition.